# C#: Adding integer to output

Tags: c#

```
{
  int x;
  x = 2;
  Console.WriteLine("Hi, Please select any number from 1,2,3,4");
  string userValue;
  userValue = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.WriteLine ("You selected: " + userValue + x);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I want value of x to be add when I select anyone from above numbers 
e.g. If I select 1 then value of x=2 should be add and answer should be "3"

Where is mistake as am not putting an integer into a bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems here: 1) userValue is a string, 2) you lack parentheses in your WriteLine. Have you tried something like :

```
 int userValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 // ....
 Console.WriteLine ("You selected: " + (userValue + x));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
            int x;
            x = 2;
            Console.WriteLine("Hi, Please select any number from 1,2,3,4");
            int userValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine ("You selected: " + (userValue + x));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

That Worked! :)